# best way to store an hotkey in preferences

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, hotkeys

I am wondering about the best way to store a hotkey in preferences in a Coco application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hotkey is really just a keyCode+modifierFlags pair that point to some chunk of code to execute.  So I'd probably do something like:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:myHotKeyKeyCode forKey:@"HotKeyKeyCode"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:myHotKeyModifierFlags forKey:@"HotKeyModifierFlags"];
```

Then when your app launches again....

```
NSInteger keyCode = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"HotKeyKeyCode"];
NSInteger modifierFlags = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"HotKeyModifierFlags"];

//register the keyCode and modifierFlags to execute some chunk of code
```

Comment: @Peter a keycode is technically an `unsigned short`, and the modifier flags should probably be `NSUInteger`, but for simplicity, yes I meant `NSInteger` ;)